# Shell : How to test if a directory exists and display a custom error message if it's not existing

Tags: bash, shell

I'm  automating  a deployment task for a web project.
The continuous integration  is done withing a gulp shell task which consists on

1. testing if the repository exists
2. if yes : copying it

the gulp script code below is doing all that :

```
gulp.task('getSQL', shell.task([
    '[ -d livraison/SQL/$(echo tag=' + util.env.tagsVersion + ' |grep -oP "(?<=v)[0-9\.]+") ] 
    && cp -r livraison/SQL/$(echo tag=' + util.env.tagsVersion + ' |grep -oP "(?<=v)[0-9\.]+")/* .'
]));
```

as you can see , the gulp task is in its integrity a succession of **shell cmds**.

**the first part** is searching the repository

**the second** is copying it

My mission , is to add a traitement which can display a custom error message in the shell console :

**MESSAGE :** "your file is not found" :* **when the file is not existing**

so how i can do it in that same code

**any suggestions ??**

Comment: This code is dangerous -- prone-to-shell-injection-vulnerabilities dangerous, if the content in the tagsVersion variable isn't tightly controlled. Why aren't you generating the directory name in JavaScript rather than doing the `echo | grep` thing?

Comment: If it were designed for security, `shell.task()` would let you pass your argument vector separate from the script text -- much as how secure SQL frameworks let you use bind variables instead of using string-substitution.

Comment: ...that said, the examples in https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-shell are showing no attention to secure practices at all, which leaves me to be... concerned... about the package as a whole.

Comment: Note in particular that gulp-shell has been blacklisted as promoting antipatterns -- at https://github.com/gulpjs/plugins/blob/master/src/blackList.json#L15. I've also filed a ticket showcasing its security vulnerabilities and how its interface could be modified to encourage better practices at https://github.com/sun-zheng-an/gulp-shell/issues/83

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[ -d "$directory" ] || { echo "Directory does not exist" >&2; exit 1; }
```